# Local tomcat server returning 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am learning REST api and running it on Tomcat Apache 7 on my local machine.

Setup:

- Tomcat Apache 7
- JAX-RS
- Java 8

I have a local mysql database that these rest apis interact with.

I can run a GET method with and without params but when I try to run a PUT method I am getting a 405 Method not allowed.  I've researched the error and can not seem to find an issues that is similar to what I am running into.

My service code is:

```
@PUT
    @Path("/users/status/{user_id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public int setInactive(@PathParam("user_id") int user_id) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        return userDao.markInActive(user_id);
    }
```

This rest api updates a field in the database.

My local tomcat server logs doesn't have related items listed.

I tried adding a filter in the web.xml file and it did not have any impact.

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
          <param-value>Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Connection,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Referer,Token-Id,User-Agent, X-Requested-With</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
          <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
          <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

This did nothing to change the outcome.

**The URL I am using is:**

```
http://localhost:8080/UserManagementTwo/rest/UserService/users/status/1
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

The @PUT was there but wasn't showing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the corrispondent method designator `@PUT`.

Change your code to:

```
@Path("/users/status/{user_id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@PUT
public int setInactive(@PathParam("user_id") int user_id) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    return userDao.markInActive(user_id);
}
```

Comment: I did have the *@PUT* designator included but for some reason it did not show in my question.  I have corrected the question..

Answer (score 0):

After looking some more I found my answer here:

[Very peculiar :HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659586/very-peculiar-http-status-405-method-not-allowed)

> The browser will issue a GET request for your resource - which you have declared as a @PUT on the server-side and are PUT-ing to it from your client-side code. The browser is trying to 'fetch' (or GET) the resource and nothing exists for @GET

I ran it in postman and it is working.

Thank you all.